# Ensuring if Python code is running on GPU or CPU

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, theano, keras

I have written some basic `Deep Learning` code having 2 `LSTM` layers. I am using `Keras` with `Theano` as my backend. This code is taking way too long on my machine on `AWS` versus another machine on `AWS`. On the machine where it's running faster, it take 640 seconds per epoch and on the machine where it's running slower it takes more than 10,000 seconds per epoch.

I am starting to think that the code on the slower machine is not running on the GPU. The codes running on both the machines are exactly the same. The machine configurations are also the same.

It looks like `Theano` is installed on the slower machine. I ran the following code and got the result:

[image]

Is there a way to check if my code is running on the GPU or the CPU?

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

TIA.

**EDIT**

As per advise from @Marcin, I added the following code:

[image]

But when I run the following code, I still get the `Used the cpu` result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to check that:

1. Check in `Theano` flags:

   ```
   import os
   print(os.environ["THEANO_FLAGS"])
   ```

   and see what `device` is set.
2. Try running this code snippet provided [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html):

code:

```
from theano import function, config, shared, tensor
import numpy
import time

vlen = 10 * 30 * 768  # 10 x #cores x # threads per core
iters = 1000

rng = numpy.random.RandomState(22)
x = shared(numpy.asarray(rng.rand(vlen), config.floatX))
f = function([], tensor.exp(x))
print(f.maker.fgraph.toposort())
t0 = time.time()
for i in range(iters):
    r = f()
t1 = time.time()
print("Looping %d times took %f seconds" % (iters, t1 - t0))
print("Result is %s" % (r,))
if numpy.any([isinstance(x.op, tensor.Elemwise) and
              ('Gpu' not in type(x.op).__name__)
              for x in f.maker.fgraph.toposort()]):
    print('Used the cpu')
else:
    print('Used the gpu')
```

**EDIT:**

Try adding this snippet as **FIRST TWO (IMPORTANT)** lines of your code:

```
import os
os.environ["THEANO_FLAGS"] = "mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu,floatX=float32"
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I ran your piece of code and indeed I got `Used the cpu`. Would you happen to know how do I change it to use the `GPU`?

Comment: Could you print out the result of your `theano` flags?

Comment: Oh God - it seems that you have not installed `Theano` at all. This could also explain enormous big training time.

Comment: Try `device=cuda` instead `device=gpu`.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you have `GPU/CUDA` on this machine?

Comment: hmmm, I'd like to be sure, but I'd like to check once again before I give you false information. Let me check this and I will get back asap.

Comment: Would you have an easy command to check these installations on `Ubuntu`? I'm sorry for these basic questions, but I'm quite new to this.

Comment: I ran `nvcc --version` and it returned `The program 'nvcc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`

I'm wondering if that means cuda is not installed.

Comment: Yes - this is exactly that. This means that you don't have `CUDA`. To be honest - I would start a new question - we went way beyond the scope of the question :)

Comment: You are absolutely right. I will start a new question. I cannot thank you enough for your help. Thanks a lot :).